# VMware automatic tuning

Tags: vmware-esxi

I am a developer not an administrator, but I have been tasked with managing an ESXi 4 installation running 3 Windows 2008 hosts.

The load on the server is very light and everything has been going fine.

Next week they are planning on adding additional load to one of the VMs and were wondering if perhaps VMware might have automatically tuned the host based on the load it had experienced so that when additional load is added, it would not perform that well.

Are there any steps I need to take to make sure it performs well with the added load?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Next week they are planning on adding additional load to one of the VMs and were wondering if perhaps VMware might have automatically tuned the host based on the load it had experienced so that when additional load is added, it would not perform that well.

It didn't. That functionality doesn't exist.

> Are there any steps I need to take to make sure it performs well with the added load?

Yes, make sure you have the resources available to handle the additional load. Just like anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, try hitting a test server with the expected amount of load and see how it handles it. There's really no substitute to trying it out and seeing how it does.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from an artificial load test ahead of time, be prepared to understand ESXi performance metrics for when the real load hits.  VMware has docs for each release ( v4.1: http://www.vmware.com/support/pubs/vs_pages/vsp_pubs_esxi41_i_vc41.html) that will get you started, specifically the Resource Management guide.